# How to confirm the aws cloudformation validate-template command from shell script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to validate cloud formation template from shell script.

I use aws cloudformation validate-tempate command:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.yaml
```

But the output of the command is a colon (:) that wait for a confirmation after execution.
How can I confirm it and check the status code of a command?

I tried `yes` command but it did not work:

```
yes q | aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the column (:) behavior you describing. Here is the expected output and status code check.

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://good-template.yaml
... dump of the template
echo $?
0 //status is OK

aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://bad-template.yaml
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 615, column 1)
echo $?
255 //status is error
```

Answer (score 1):

[`aws cloudformation validate-template`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) doesn't validate much. I'd recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/), which will catch many more issues before deploying. The [Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) can show all of those errors inline while authoring templates as well